# Create a new column with value in another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hel,lo I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups   Names                          COLs  COLe
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    2     300
G1     SDDD1                            NA    NA
G1     SKUD.2.                          NA    NA
G1     SEQUENCE3                        NA    NA
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  400   600
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus    20    200
G2     OP_D:500-1000():Felis_catus      500   1000
G2     JDJDJ99                          NA    NA
```

and I would like to add a new column `Names2` and put within groups the all `Names` without `()` in it content against every `Names` with `()` in its content :

The output would be :

```
Groups   Names                          Names2    COLs  COLe
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    SDDD1     2     300
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    SKUD.2.   2     300
G1     ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    SEQUENCE3 2     300
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  SDDD1     400   600
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  SKUD.2.   400   600
G1     ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  SEQUENCE3 400   600
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus    SDDD1     20    200
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus    SKUD.2.   20    200
G1     IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus    SEQUENCE3 20    200
G2     OP_D:500-1000():Felis_catus      JDJDJ99   500   1000
```

Does someone have an idea using pandas ?

Comment: does the name (e.g. JDJDJ99) always follow the oroginal string name in row order?

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand the question? you mean does the Names without the () always follow a name with a () ? is yes the answer is no

Comment: how do you related the names2 to which name? what's the logic for example for SDDD1 to be allocated to 'ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus', is just because it's following it until  anew Name ID appears? 
Also, are those 'NA' strings or Nan?

Comment: the Names that are put into Names2 are all Names that  do not have a `()` in its string (ex: SDDD1), and are allocated to all Names that do have a `() `in their string with all combinations possible within groups. That is why `ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus , BC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus and IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus`  all have allocated the three Names without `()` (  `SDDD1  ,SKUD.2. and SEQUENCE3`). And NA are 'NA'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = df[df.Names.str.contains('()', regex=False)]
df2 = df[~df.Names.str.contains('()', regex=False)][['Groups', 'Names']]

print( pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='Groups').rename(columns={"Names_x": "Names", "Names_y": "Names2"}) )
```

Prints:

```
  Groups                            Names   COLs    COLe     Names2
0     G1    ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    2.0   300.0      SDDD1
1     G1    ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    2.0   300.0    SKUD.2.
2     G1    ABC_DEF.1:2-300():Canis_lupus    2.0   300.0  SEQUENCE3
3     G1  ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  400.0   600.0      SDDD1
4     G1  ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  400.0   600.0    SKUD.2.
5     G1  ABC_DEF.1:400-600():Canis_lupus  400.0   600.0  SEQUENCE3
6     G1    IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus   20.0   200.0      SDDD1
7     G1    IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus   20.0   200.0    SKUD.2.
8     G1    IJK_LMN.1:20-200():Bos_taurus   20.0   200.0  SEQUENCE3
9     G2      OP_D:500-1000():Felis_catus  500.0  1000.0    JDJDJ99
```